# Add comment to cell if cell in other column contains value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that combines the cell contents of all cells in column C:F and puts that into a comment on column B - per row.
I now need to apply that only to rows that have content in their respective column A.

Cell A2 has something in it, so put the contents of C2:F2 into the comment of B2.
Cell A3 has nothing in it, so don't add a comment to that cell.
Cell A4 has something in it again, so put the contents of C4:F4 into the comment of B4.

The table looks something like this: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnHcq.png)

My code so far looks like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim LRow As Integer
    
    With ActiveSheet
        For LRow = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(Cells(LRow, 3), Cells(LRow, 6)).Select
        
        Dim c As Range, s As String

        With Cells(LRow, 2)
            .ClearComments
            For Each c In Selection
            'If c.Offset(0, -2) <> "" Then
                'On Error Resume Next
                If c <> "" Then s = IIf(s = "", c, s & Chr(10) & c)
                Next c
                .AddCommentThreaded "Test:" & Chr(10) & s
        End With
        s = ""
        Next LRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Problem now being that I can't get the content check in column A to work. Anyone have any hints on how to get that bit to work?

Comment: `If Range("A" & lRow).Value <> ""` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below. Also [checkout how to avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and [why use long instead of integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689021/11732320)

```
Sub Test()
    Dim LRow As Long, aCell As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    With ws
    
        For LRow = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(LRow, 1).Value <> "" Then
                Dim theComment As String
                theComment = ""
                
                For Each aCell In Intersect(Range("C:F"), .Rows(LRow)).Cells
                    theComment = theComment & aCell.Value
                Next aCell
    
            With .Cells(LRow, 2)
                .ClearComments
                    .AddCommentThreaded "Test:" & Chr(10) & theComment
            End With
            End If
            
        Next LRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I very much thank you, good person. Very much what I was looking for, just couldn't get the position for the column 1 check down - also, ty the general tips, cheers.